# Нахождение спецсимволов в строке, узнать какой именно с перечня

Tags: php, массивы

Есть простой функционал синонимайзера, в котором текст разбивается по пробелу explode. Потом каждое слово заменяется синонимом с БД. Тут все ровно. Проблема в спецсимволах. Задача стоит определить есть ли рядом со словом спецсимвол, убрать его для точного запроса к БД, а на выходе поставить именно этот спецсимвол на место в связке с полученым с БД синонимом.

```
$text = "Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.";
$toktext = explode (" ", $text);
$specsimv_array = [",", ":", "."];//на самом деле намного больше
foreach ($toktext as $key_tok => $word_tok)
{
  //запрос к базе и получение синонима начального слова
  $newword[$key_tok] = $sinonim;//записываем синоним для замены в конечный массив
}
$textSin = implode(" ", $newword);
```

Задача после синонимизации после синонима слова "булок" поставить именно запятую, а после "чаю" именно точку

Раньше был громоздкий неправильный код

```
 $pos = stripos ($word_tok, ","); //проверяем, есть ли рядом со словом запятая
 $pos1 = stripos ($word_tok, ":"); //проверяем, есть ли рядом со словом двоеточие
 $pos2 = stripos ($word_tok, "."); //проверяем, есть ли рядом со словом точка
 if ($pos !== false) {$word_tok = str_replace(",", "", $word_tok);} //если есть запятая, удаляем ее
 if ($pos1 !== false) {$word_tok = str_replace(":", "", $word_tok);} //если есть двоеточие, удаляем ее
 if ($pos2 !== false) {$word_tok = str_replace(".", "", $word_tok);} //если есть точка, удаляем ее
```

а после получения синонима:

```
 if ($pos !== false) {$sinonim .= ',';} //если изначально была запятая, добавляем ее
 if ($pos1 !== false) {$sinonim .= ':';} //если изначально было двоеточие, добавляем его
 if ($pos2 !== false) {$sinonim .= '.';} //если изначально была точка, добавляем ее
```

Но спецсимволов становится все больше и хотелось бы реализовать все через поиск в массиве. Задача определить есть ли спецсимвол, определить КАКОЙ спецсимвол и именно его прилепить после синонима. Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, разделяйте ваш текст с помощью `preg_split()` с сохранением разделителей. Потом проведите замену, и склейте все как было. В примере кода ниже, вместо синонимов слово приводится в верхний регистр.

```
$text = "Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.";

$data = preg_split("/([\s,\.;])/", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

foreach($data as $idx => $word){
    if(strlen($word) == 1) continue;
    $data[$idx] = mb_strtoupper($word); // замена на синоним
}

print_r([$text,  implode("", $data)]);
```

На выходе имеем следующий результат:

```
Array (
    [0] => Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.
    [1] => СЪЕШЬ ЕЩЁ ЭТИХ МЯГКИХ ФРАНЦУЗСКИХ БУЛОК, ДА ВЫПЕЙ ЧАЮ.
)
```

Comment: Это очень близко к тому, что мне необходимо. Вы меня натолкнули на решение просто добавлять все символы в перечень в регулярку и все. Получается, что начальный текст разбивается в массив, а спецсимволы являются его элементами и на выходе становятся куда надо. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Откажитесь от `explode` и все станет просто

```
$text = "Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.";
$delims = [' ', ',', ':', '.'];//на самом деле намного больше
$textSin = '';
$word = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
  if (in_array($text[$i], $delims)) {
    if ($word !== '') {
      $textSin += get_db_sin($word);
      $word = '';
    }
    $textSin += $text[$i];
  } else
    $word += $text[$i];
}
if ($word !== '') {
  $textSin += get_db_sin($word);
```

Мультибайтовую кодировку допилите самостоятельно

Comment: Вопрос по коду, но не по теме. Не могу выявить ошибку в строке:
if ($word !== '') {
Ошибка: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: @СергейСтрельченко С кавычками не напутали? Там два одинарных апострофа

Comment: Нашел ошибку: не закрыта скобка при проверке in_array

Comment: Совсем непонятно откуда берется `$word`. Зачем циклом перебирать каждый символ в начальном тексте, если работа ведется со словами? Даже если брать английский текст, то на выходе мы получаем 0.

Comment: @СергейСтрельченко Чтобы работать со словами, нужно их вначале выделить из текста. Для этого нужно перебрать все символы и определить, что это за символ. Если это буква, то мы добавляем его к текущему слову `$word` если это не буква, то мы считаем, что текущее слово `$word` сформировано. Мы ищем для этого слова синоним, а сам символ добавляем к результирующей строке